# Where does the browser fail as a client

Tags: browser, user-interface, rich-internet-application

Where should the browser be improved upon to help improve application experiences?

For instance some of my main gripes are 
A) Different browsers will need different configurations / plugins (I dont want to download different JRE's, RIA platforms such as flash, silverright, gears so forth)

B) I want to always be able to drag data from my desktop to a 'Webapp'. I don't like clicking browse for file and then uploading it. I think this is something that should be easily handled.

Additionally based on the above point - I'd like for it to be very easy to drag information from a web page to my computer to be used in whatever shape form or matter needed. For instance I'd like if I could drag my user ID from stack overflow into my mail / crm client which would take relevant information and maybe even build a picture up of my knowledge.

What else am I missing ?

Comment: BTW, B is allowed in Safari on OSX.

Comment: Well I've found its possible one way or another in most browsers. But I want true rich content transfer - something similar to how I can pull an excel into a word document. 

My gripe is the browser seems so primitive.

Answer (score 1):

I see that current problem is ever-growing pile of technologies. Just connect straight to users browser API calls via RPC. RPC is future way to go and it puts end to this tech-piling-up-trend. Currently security is too weak for this kind of technology. Maybe some sort of virtual sandbox would fix that.

See RPyc [theory of operation](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/theory) and [screencast](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/screencasts#part1), it explains the idea pretty well.